# Creating a "Shell" for fragments in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm busy creating an application that uses fragments and tabs. However I was the tabs to do different things depending on which fragment is called.

Here is my main method, What I'm trying to accomplish here is instantiating the activity_main.xml which is listed below and in that xml I'll load a fragment in, this way I can alter the way the tabs work depending on which fragment is called.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        //Fragment manager deals with switching fragments within the viewpager
        final FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FavoriteFragment FF = new FavoriteFragment();
        final PlaceholderFragment HF = new PlaceholderFragment();
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                if (tabId == R.id.tab_home)
                {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeFragment.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                if (tabId == R.id.tab_favorites)
                {
                    FM.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragContainer,FF).commit();

                }
                else if (tabId == R.id.tab_booked)
                {

                }
                if (tabId == R.id.tab_inbox)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InboxActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if (tabId == R.id.tab_profile)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SEE";
                case 1:
                    return "DO";
                case 2:
                    return "STAY";
                case 3:
                    return "ENJOY";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.iconiccode.where.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="105dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragContainer">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </RelativeLayout>
   <!--Bottom Bar-->


    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Homefragment, This is the first fragment behind called.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

            @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            int tabNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            String tabHeader = "";
            switch (tabNumber)
            {
                case 1:
                    tabHeader="Top Attractions to See";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tabHeader="Do This";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tabHeader="Stay Here";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tabHeader="Enjoy This";
                    break;
            }
            textView.setText(tabHeader);
            RecyclerView bookedRecycler =(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bookedRecycler);
            RecyclerView vendorRecycler =(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.vendorRecycler);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager vendorLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager bookedLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

            vendorRecycler.setLayoutManager(vendorLM);
            bookedRecycler.setLayoutManager(bookedLM);

            VendorAdapter venAdapter = new VendorAdapter();
            vendorRecycler.setAdapter(venAdapter);

            BookedAdapter bookAdapter = new BookedAdapter();
            bookedRecycler.setAdapter(bookAdapter);

            return rootView;
        }
```

Doing this this way gives me an
"Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.iconiccode.where/com.iconiccode.where.fragments.HomeFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

I have read that there is no need to declare fragments but even after declaring them I still have the same issues. I'm not entirely sure I'm even going about this the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are populating the fragment in a wrong way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

This is the way to initialize activity not the fragment  you can look at [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/05/android-working-with-fragments.html) tutorial , provided link will explain the process you need to follow for populating a fragment in your activity

Comment: and http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/ this is tutorial fro tabs fragment with the "swipe to move next fragment" funcionality

Comment: What I'm trying to do though is have the tabs/bottom bar global and the content inbetween switched depending what fragment is called, the example shows the fragment under one  xml, is the the way it needs to be done ? or am I looking at this whole thing wrong ?

Comment: you are thinking perfectly but your doing it in a wrong way.. follow the link truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager

Comment: let me explain alil bit. You should have a single activity with tabs and a container. the container wil be used to display the frgaments and to diaplay the framents we use supportFragmentmangers

Comment: i agree with this statement, it seems viable